# Can't get rid of the app image or launch image from my app?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

I'm trying to get rid of my launch image and app icon for my app in xcode 4 and I can't seem to at all. I've deleted the images from my project and even looked through my Info.plist and deleted all references to any of the images, and deleted from my test device, and it still appears from a fresh build.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you cleaned the project (Product > Clean)?

Comment: I had not. Very new to this process. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference there are generally two steps that need to be taken:

1) Clean the current project (CMD+Shift+K)

2) Delete the app from your phone! This is important because the phone caches certain resources.